# How to deduce function $f$ given level sets at intersections with axes?

Tags: vector-analysis

How to deduce function $f$ given level sets at intersections with axes?

So given level set

$$f(x,y,z)=k$$

and its intersection points:
$$f(x,0,0) \text{ at } (k^3,0,0)$$
$$f(0,y,0) \text{ at } (0,\text{some f(k) e.g. } 2k^2,0)$$
$$f(0,0,z) \text{ at } (0, 0, \text{some f(k)})$$

Then how can I deduce, what $f$ is?

Is $f$ necessarily unique?

Comment: What does "and so on..." mean here? Does $f(0,y,0) = k^3$ as well?

Comment: This is only a partial answer, but $f(x,0,0)$ must be one of -1, 0, or 1 for all $x$. This is because, for $y = z = 0$, $f(x,y,z) = f(x,0,0)$, and so $k = k^3$. This is assuming that what you mean is $f(x,0,0) = f^3(x,y,z), \forall x,y,z$

Comment: @CulDeVu So the level set to $x$ direction occurs only on three points. But how does this tell anything about $f(x,y,z)$? If $f(x,y,z)=f(x,0,0)$ is equivalent to saying that $k=k^3$ must be satisfied, then could it be true that $f(x,0,0)=x^3-x$? Particularly, because whatever $y$ and $z$ would be, they cannot equal $0$, unless $x$ satisfies $x^3-x$?

Comment: If the property $f(x,0,0) = f^3(x,y,z)$ holds for all x,y,z, then the only thing any $f(x,0,0)$ could equal is -1, 0, or 1. In particular, if f is continuous, then the entire function $f(x,y,z)$ must be constant: -1, 0, or 1.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It seems like I misunderstood the question. Disregard.

Answering under the assumption that we're looking for all functions $f$ such that $f(x,0,0) = f^3(x,y,z)$ for all real $x,y,z$.

Fix $x$ and choose $y = z = 0$. So, $f(x,0,0) = f^3(x,0,0)$, and thus $f(x,0,0) \in \{-1, 0, 1\}$ for any $x$.

Now fix $x,y,$ and $z$. Note that $q = q^{\frac{1}{3}}$ for each $q \in \{-1, 0, 1\}$, so that means that $f(x,y,z) = f(x,0,0)$ for all $x,y,z$ reals. So, your function can be thought of as just a bunch of constant $yz$ planes, each of whose value is completely determined by the $x$ coord the plane passes through.

The only continuous functions that satisfy the rule are the 3 constant functions $f(x,y,z) = -1, 0,$ or $1$.

Comment: I didn't say that the other intersections occur for $k^3$ though. But can be some other function of $k$, e.g. $2k^2$.

Comment: So $f(x,0,0) = f^3(x,y,z)$ for only one such $x,y,z$?

Comment: The x-intersection occurs at $(k^3, 0, 0)$. The y-intersection may occur using some other function e.g. at $(0, 2k^2,0)$. Add yet some other function of $k$ for $z$-intersection.